# No route matches [GET] "/book/list"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

I am using Rails 3.2.7. I have a controller and a action as it's shown below:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController

   def list
      @books = Book.find(:all)
   end

end
```

I also created a model with the name `book.rb` under model  and a `list.rhtml` inside `\app\views\book` folder. When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:3000/book/list`, I am getting this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/book/list"**
```

Here's `config/routes.rb`:

```
Ravi::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # rest of the explanations in default "config/routes.rb"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your router config is all commented out, you need to add the rules yourself.

***[Guiders: Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)***

Try add the below:

```
resources :books do
  get 'list', :on => :collection
end
```

And access with: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/books/list`

Comment: Thanks a lot , i modified that , but i am getting this error , pleas see the screen shot here http://postimage.org/image/subaz7t8n/

Comment: +1 For linking to the very good Rails guide on routing. And the comment.

Comment: I did that ie renaming file to list.erb.html , but still the same Exception .

Comment: @PreethiJain, sorry, it should be `list.html.erb`.