# No route matches [GET] "/book/list" part II: The Route Revenge of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow this [rails tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-views.htm) but I am having a lot of issues due to version mismatches. I followed the instructions exactly and I really understand everything up until now but I can't seem to resolve this routing issue on my own. [I read a good deal about routes independently](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but can't figure out what to do. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444217/no-route-matches-get-book-list) has been posted once before on stackoverflow but that solution does not work for me because of version issues

**Error Message:**

```
No route matches [GET] "/book/list"
```

When trying to access `http://localhost:3000/book/list`.

***Code***

***route.rb***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources: :books
end
```

**views>book>list.rhtml**

```
<% if @books.blank? %>
<p>There are not any books currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current books in our system</p>
<ul id="books">
<% @books.each do |c| %>
<li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
```

**models>book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
end
```

**models>subject.rb**

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end
```

**controllers>book_controller.rb**

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
    def list
        @books = Book.find(:all)
    end
    def show
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end
    def new
        @book = Book.new
        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
    end
    def create
        @book = Book.new(params[:book])
        if @book.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
        else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
    def edit
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
    end
    def update
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
            redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
        else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
    def delete
        Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
    end
    def show_subjects
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: typo: the controller should be pluralized: `class BooksController` (and the file `books_controller`)

Comment: That is a really, really old tutorial. Rails has changed massively since it was written. Please use a more recent tutorial. This [official Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) is excellent.

Comment: BTW,the title `The Route Revenge Of Rails` seems funny :)

Comment: @Jordan Yeah you're right. Been having issues through every step of this tutorial and thought it was just me, thanks for pointing that out though. I'll try that tutorial instead.

Comment: @Jordan That's the point! lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I'm seeing. For one, your controller should be `BooksController` and not `BookController` (you'll also need to ensure it's in a file called `books_controller.rb`). Two, when you do `resources :books`, Rails will create the following routes

```
GET /books -> index
GET /books/:id -> show
GET /books/:id/edit -> edit
PUT /books/:id -> update
GET /books/new -> new
POST /books -> create
DELETE /books/:id -> destroy
```

As you can see, `list` is not one of the routes created, which is why you're getting that error message.

Comment: Why would `list` will not generate as a `route`? The OP has `list` method in the controller.

Comment: Routes are generated from the routes.rb (or whatever runs in the Application.routes.draw block) not from controller methods.

Comment: @Pavan sure, but he doesn't have a route definition for it, so no such route will exist. He would need to explicitly add a collection route called `list` in order for that to be routable. See [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `resources :books` in your `routes`.So your controller Class name should be Plural ie., `BooksController` not `BookController`.So is the error.

Change your controller class name to `BooksController` and your filename to `books_controller.rb`

**OR**

update your `routes` to

```
resource :book #not singular
```

**Note:** I prefer the first way,because it suites the `Rails convention`

**Update**

You have to update your `routes` to like this

```
resources :books do
  collection do
    get 'list'
  end
end
```

This will enable Rails to recognize the path **`/books/list`** with **`GET`**, and route to the **`list`** action of **`BooksController`**.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @BartJedrocha's answer, first of all with your current routes i.e.

```
resources: :books
```

your application should not work and give you a Syntax error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`.

As `resources` is a method invocation with argument `:books`.
So your route should be

```
resources :books ## Notice no : after "resources"
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavan! What beats me is how OP's server is even running with the current route.

Comment: Yeah! That seems very interesting :D